# Neural Network in C for XOR, outputs all converge to same value

Tags: c, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, backpropagation

While the problem in the title is a specific one (converging to same value *just for sigmoid*, with other activation functions costs are not reduced in general), my network is buggy in general, and after many hours spent debugging/testing I cannot figure out why, even after catching some minor mistakes. Doing the back propagation on paper for the first training epoch aligned with what the function was doing.

I hate to say that I do not know the issue with my network. I'd appreciate if someone could look over it to hint me at what part(s) of my network implementation are wrong.

**What I have Tried**

- Different Activation Functions
- Different Weight Initialization Methods (both Xavier and random)

**Example (XOR)**

Results after 20,000 epochs:

```
Inputs = 1.000000 0.000000, Target Outputs = 1.000000, Predicted Outputs = 0.028415.
Inputs = 0.000000 1.000000, Target Outputs = 1.000000, Predicted Outputs = 0.028452.
Inputs = 1.000000 1.000000, Target Outputs = 0.000000, Predicted Outputs = 0.028426.
Inputs = 0.000000 0.000000, Target Outputs = 0.000000, Predicted Outputs = 0.028441.
```

**Note**

Since I am not providing `data.c` (since it would make the post extensively long, as it loads data from the `csv` files), trust that `input` and `targetOutput` in the `train` method of `model.c`, after `initInput` and `initTargetOutput` have been applied to them, they contain the values of the input, `[1 or 0, 1 or 0]` and the target output, `[1 or 0]`. I have completely verified this myself.

**GitHub**

The repository containing the below files is located [here](https://github.com/TheeNinja/NeuralNetwork). My apologies for not including it in the pre-edited post. Do note that there are many sections of code within the repository that are surrounded by `#if` `#else` macros (one for gradient checking, the others for toggling printing). Those are beyond the scope of this post (thus I have removed them in the below files).

**model.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include "model.h"
#include "functions.h"

/**
 * @param model
 * @param input The head to ann input array of size <code>model.neuronsPerLayer[INPUT_LAYER]</code> that has the inputs
 * of the model.
 */
void setInput(struct Model* model, double input[]) {
    model->values[INPUT_LAYER] = input;
}

void propagateInputForward(struct Model* model, double input[]) {
    setInput(model, input);

    for (int endLayerIndex = 1; endLayerIndex < NUMBER_OF_LAYERS; endLayerIndex++) {
        int startLayerIndex = endLayerIndex - 1;

        int endNeuronCount = model->neuronsPerLayer[endLayerIndex];
        int startNeuronCount = model->neuronsPerLayer[startLayerIndex];

        for (int endNeuronIndex = 0; endNeuronIndex < endNeuronCount; endNeuronIndex++) {
            double weightedSum = 0.0;
            double bias = model->biases[endLayerIndex][endNeuronIndex];
            
            for (int startNeuronIndex = 0; startNeuronIndex < startNeuronCount; startNeuronIndex++) {
                double weight = model->weights[endLayerIndex][endNeuronIndex][startNeuronIndex];
                double startNeuronValue = model->values[startLayerIndex][startNeuronIndex];
                
                double weightedInfluence = weight * startNeuronValue;
                weightedSum += weightedInfluence;
            }

            weightedSum += bias;

            double activatedNeuronValue = model->getActivation(weightedSum);
            
            model->values[endLayerIndex][endNeuronIndex] = activatedNeuronValue;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @param model The model which the parameter gradients will be based on.
 * @param layerIndex The layer index whose weight deltas are being calculated.
 * @param baseDelta The base delta, equal to change in the cost function over change in
 * the weighted sum of the neuron value.
 * @param weightGradients The weight gradient to fill.
 * @param biasGradients The bias gradient to fill.
 */
void updateParameterGradients(struct Model *model, const double* targetOutput, double** weightGradients[],
                              double* biasGradients[]) {
    int outputNeuronCount = model->neuronsPerLayer[OUTPUT_LAYER];

    // Entry indexed by [layerIndex][neuronIndex] gives
    // Δ C / Δ Z[layerIndex, neuronIndex]
    double* errors[NUMBER_OF_LAYERS];

    errors[OUTPUT_LAYER] = malloc(sizeof(double) * outputNeuronCount);

    // Fill errors of output layers
    for (int outputNeuronIndex = 0; outputNeuronIndex < outputNeuronCount; outputNeuronIndex++) {
        double outputNeuronValue = model->values[OUTPUT_LAYER][outputNeuronIndex];
        double targetOutputNeuronValue = targetOutput[outputNeuronIndex];

        // Δ C_outputNeuronIndex / Δ A[OUTPUT_LAYER][outputNeuronIndex]
        double firstErrorComponent = model->getCostDerivative(outputNeuronValue, targetOutputNeuronValue);
        // Δ A[OUTPUT_LAYER][outputNeuronIndex] / Δ Z[OUTPUT_LAYER][outputNeuronIndex]
        double secondErrorComponent = model->getActivationDerivative(outputNeuronValue);
        // Δ C_outputNeuronIndex / Δ Z[OUTPUT_LAYER][outputNeuronIndex]
        double error = firstErrorComponent * secondErrorComponent;

        errors[OUTPUT_LAYER][outputNeuronIndex] = error; 
    }

    // Fill errors of non-output layers
    for (int endLayerIndex = OUTPUT_LAYER; endLayerIndex > INPUT_LAYER; endLayerIndex--) {
        int startLayerIndex = endLayerIndex - 1;

        int startNeuronsCount = model->neuronsPerLayer[startLayerIndex];
        int endNeuronsCount = model->neuronsPerLayer[endLayerIndex];

        errors[startLayerIndex] = malloc(sizeof(double) * startNeuronsCount);

        for (int startNeuronIndex = 0; startNeuronIndex < startNeuronsCount; startNeuronIndex++) {
            double error = 0.0;

            for (int endNeuronIndex = 0; endNeuronIndex < endNeuronsCount; endNeuronIndex++) {
                double nextError = errors[endLayerIndex][endNeuronIndex];
                double nextWeight = model->weights[endLayerIndex][endNeuronIndex][startNeuronIndex];

                double activationValue = model->values[startLayerIndex][startNeuronIndex];
                double activationValueDelta = model->getActivationDerivative(activationValue);

                double errorInfluence = nextWeight * nextError * activationValueDelta;
                error += errorInfluence;
            }

            errors[startLayerIndex][startNeuronIndex] = error;
            }
    }

    // Update weights and biases of all layers based on errors
    for (int endLayerIndex = OUTPUT_LAYER; endLayerIndex > INPUT_LAYER; endLayerIndex--) {
        int startLayerIndex = endLayerIndex - 1;

        int endNeuronCount = model->neuronsPerLayer[endLayerIndex];
        int startNeuronCount = model->neuronsPerLayer[startLayerIndex];

        for (int endNeuronIndex = 0; endNeuronIndex < endNeuronCount; endNeuronIndex++) {
            double endNeuronError = errors[endLayerIndex][endNeuronIndex];

            double biasGradientInfluence = endNeuronError;
            biasGradients[endLayerIndex][endNeuronIndex] += biasGradientInfluence;

            for (int startNeuronIndex = 0; startNeuronIndex < startNeuronCount; startNeuronIndex++) {
                double startNeuronValue = model->values[startLayerIndex][startNeuronIndex];

                double weightGradientInfluence = endNeuronError * startNeuronValue;
                weightGradients[endLayerIndex][endNeuronIndex][startNeuronIndex] += weightGradientInfluence;
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Updates the weight and bias values within {@code model}, given the gradients of the cost function
 * with respect to the weights and biases.
 *
 * @param model
 * @param weightGradients
 * @param biasGradients
 */
void updateParameterValues(struct Model* model, double** weightGradients[], double* biasGradients[], int batchSize) {
    for (int endLayerIndex = 1; endLayerIndex < NUMBER_OF_LAYERS; endLayerIndex++) {
        int endNeuronCount = model->neuronsPerLayer[endLayerIndex];

        int startLayerIndex = endLayerIndex - 1;
        int startNeuronCount = model->neuronsPerLayer[startLayerIndex];

        for (int endNeuronIndex = 0; endNeuronIndex < endNeuronCount; endNeuronIndex++) {
            double biasDelta = biasGradients[endLayerIndex][endNeuronIndex];
            biasDelta /= batchSize;
            biasDelta *= model->learningRate;

            // update bias
            model->biases[endLayerIndex][endNeuronIndex] -= biasDelta;

            for (int startNeuronIndex = 0; startNeuronIndex < startNeuronCount; startNeuronIndex++) {
                double weightDelta = weightGradients[endLayerIndex][endNeuronIndex][startNeuronIndex];

                weightDelta /= batchSize;
                weightDelta *= model->learningRate;

                // update weight
                model->weights[endLayerIndex][endNeuronIndex][startNeuronIndex] -= weightDelta;
            }
        }
    }
}

static int epochIndex = 0;

void initGradients(struct Model* model, double** weightGradients[], double* biasGradients[]) {
    for (int endLayerIndex = 1; endLayerIndex < NUMBER_OF_LAYERS; endLayerIndex++) {
        int endNeuronCount = model->neuronsPerLayer[endLayerIndex];

        int startLayerIndex = endLayerIndex - 1;
        int startNeuronCount = model->neuronsPerLayer[startLayerIndex];

        biasGradients[endLayerIndex] = malloc(sizeof(double) * endNeuronCount);
        weightGradients[endLayerIndex] = malloc(sizeof(double*) * endNeuronCount);

        for (int endNeuronIndex = 0; endNeuronIndex < endNeuronCount; endNeuronIndex++) {
            biasGradients[endLayerIndex][endNeuronIndex] = 0.0;
            weightGradients[endLayerIndex][endNeuronIndex] = malloc(sizeof(double) * startNeuronCount);

            for (int startNeuronIndex = 0; startNeuronIndex < startNeuronCount; startNeuronIndex++)
                weightGradients[endLayerIndex][endNeuronIndex][startNeuronIndex] = 0.0;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Feeds the input values of the entry into the input array given.
 *
 * @param input
 * @param entry
 * @param inputColumnIndices
 * @param inputColumnIndicesCount
 */
void initInput(double input[], const double entry[], const int inputColumnIndices[], int inputColumnIndicesCount) {
    for (int inputColumnIndex = 0; inputColumnIndex < inputColumnIndicesCount; inputColumnIndex++) {
        int inputColumn = inputColumnIndices[inputColumnIndex];
        input[inputColumnIndex] = entry[inputColumn];
    }
}

/**
 * Feeds the target output values of entry given into the target output array given.
 *
 * @param targetOutput
 * @param entry
 * @param outputColumnIndices
 * @param outputColumnIndicesCount
 */
void initTargetOutput(double targetOutput[], const double entry[], const int outputColumnIndices[], int outputColumnIndicesCount) {
    for (int outputColumnIndex = 0; outputColumnIndex < outputColumnIndicesCount; outputColumnIndex++) {
        int outputColumn = outputColumnIndices[outputColumnIndex];
        targetOutput[outputColumnIndex] = entry[outputColumn];
    }
}

void test(struct Model* model, struct Data* data, int inputColumnIndices[], int outputColumnIndices[], double** predictedOutputs, double costs[]) {
    int inputNeuronCount = model->neuronsPerLayer[INPUT_LAYER];
    int outputNeuronCount = model->neuronsPerLayer[OUTPUT_LAYER];

    for (int entryIndex = 0; entryIndex < data->numberOfEntries; entryIndex++) {
        double *entry = data->elements[entryIndex];

        double input[inputNeuronCount];
        double targetOutput[outputNeuronCount];

        initInput(input, entry, inputColumnIndices, inputNeuronCount);
        initTargetOutput(targetOutput, entry, outputColumnIndices, outputNeuronCount);

        // forward propagation
        propagateInputForward(model, input);
        double cost = 0.0;

        for (int outputIndex = 0; outputIndex < outputNeuronCount; outputIndex++) {
            double value = model->values[OUTPUT_LAYER][outputIndex];
            predictedOutputs[entryIndex][outputIndex] = value;

            double targetValue = targetOutput[outputIndex];
            cost += model->getCost(value, targetValue);
        }

        // Take average cost
        cost /= outputNeuronCount;

        costs[entryIndex] = cost;
    }
}

void freeGradients(struct Model* model, double** weightGradients[], double** biasGradients) {
    for (int endLayerIndex = 1; endLayerIndex < NUMBER_OF_LAYERS; endLayerIndex++) {
        free(biasGradients[endLayerIndex]);

        int endNeuronCount = model->neuronsPerLayer[endLayerIndex];

        for (int neuronIndex = 0; neuronIndex < endNeuronCount; neuronIndex++)
            free(weightGradients[endLayerIndex][neuronIndex]);
    }
}

/**
 * Trains the model on the given data.
 *
 * @param model
 * @param data Container for the data the model will be trained on.
 * @param inputColumnIndices The indices of the columns within {@code data} that are the input columns.
 * @param outputColumnIndices The indices of the columns within {@code data} that are the output columns.
 */
void train(struct Model* model, struct Data* data, int inputColumnIndices[], int outputColumnIndices[]) {
    // For both weightGradients and biasGradients, index 0 is not occupied.
    // [endLayerIndex][endNeuronIndex in layerIndex][startNeuronIndex in layerIndex - 1]
    double** weightGradients[NUMBER_OF_LAYERS];
    // [endLayerIndex][endNeuronIndex]
    double* biasGradients[NUMBER_OF_LAYERS];

    // Allocate the storage for the weight and bias deltas, in addition
    // to initializing them all weight and bias deltas with values of 0
    initGradients(model, weightGradients, biasGradients);

    int inputNeuronCount = model->neuronsPerLayer[INPUT_LAYER];
    int outputNeuronCount = model->neuronsPerLayer[OUTPUT_LAYER];
    epochIndex++;

    // Feed each input into model
    for (int entryIndex = 0; entryIndex < data->numberOfEntries; entryIndex++) {
        double* entry = data->elements[entryIndex];

        double input[inputNeuronCount];
        double targetOutput[outputNeuronCount];

        // Feed values of entry into input and targetOutput given indices of input and output columns
        initInput(input, entry, inputColumnIndices, inputNeuronCount);
        initTargetOutput(targetOutput, entry, outputColumnIndices, outputNeuronCount);

        // forward propagation
        propagateInputForward(model, input);

        // update weight and bias gradients based on this entry, part of the batch
        updateParameterGradients(model, targetOutput, weightGradients, biasGradients);
    }
    
    updateParameterValues(model, weightGradients, biasGradients, data->numberOfEntries);

    freeGradients(model, weightGradients, biasGradients);
}

/**
 * Allocates the memory for the parameters (weights and biases) of the model, in addition to initializing
 * them to their default values.
 *
 * @param model
 */
void initParameters(struct Model* model) {
    // initialize weights with arbitrary
    for (int endLayerIndex = 1; endLayerIndex < NUMBER_OF_LAYERS; endLayerIndex++) {
        int endNeuronCount = model->neuronsPerLayer[endLayerIndex];

        int startLayerIndex = endLayerIndex - 1;
        int startNeuronCount = model->neuronsPerLayer[startLayerIndex];

        model->weights[endLayerIndex] = malloc(sizeof(double*) * endNeuronCount);

        for (int endNeuronIndex = 0; endNeuronIndex < endNeuronCount; endNeuronIndex++) {
            model->weights[endLayerIndex][endNeuronIndex] = malloc(sizeof(double) * startNeuronCount);
            model->biases[endLayerIndex] = malloc(sizeof(double) * endNeuronCount);

            for (int startNeuronIndex = 0; startNeuronIndex < startNeuronCount; startNeuronIndex++) {
                model->weights[endLayerIndex][endNeuronIndex][startNeuronIndex] = model->getInitialWeightValue(startNeuronCount, endNeuronCount);
                model->biases[endLayerIndex][endNeuronIndex] = model->getInitialBiasValue(startNeuronCount, endNeuronCount);
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Allocayes the memory for the values of the model.
 *
 * @param model
 */
void initValues(struct Model* model) {
    for (int layerIndex = 0; layerIndex < NUMBER_OF_LAYERS; layerIndex++) {
        int neuronsInLayer = model->neuronsPerLayer[layerIndex];
        model->values[layerIndex] = malloc(sizeof(double) * neuronsInLayer);
    }
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <zconf.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "model.h"
#include "functions.h"
#include "data.h"

#define EPOCH_COUNT 20000
#define NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS 3
#define TRAIN_ENTRIES_SIZE 4
#define TEST_ENTRIES_SIZE 4

int main() {
    time_t currentTime;
    time(&currentTime);
    srand(currentTime);

    struct Model model = {
            .neuronsPerLayer = {2, 2, 1},
            .learningRate = 0.02,

            // Default values
            .getActivation = applySigmoid,
            .getActivationDerivative = applySigmoidDerivative,
            .getCost = getCost,
            .getCostDerivative = getCostDerivative,
            .getInitialWeightValue = getInitialRandomWeight,
            .getInitialBiasValue = getInitialBias,
    };

    int numberOfInputs = model.neuronsPerLayer[INPUT_LAYER];
    int numberOfOutputs = model.neuronsPerLayer[OUTPUT_LAYER];

    // Change working directory so data can be referenced relative to parent data folder
    chdir("..");

    struct Data trainData;
    fill(&trainData, "data/xor/train.csv", NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS, TRAIN_ENTRIES_SIZE);

    struct Data testData;
    fill(&testData, "data/xor/test.csv", NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS, TEST_ENTRIES_SIZE);

    int inputColumnIndices[numberOfInputs];
    int outputColumnIndices[numberOfOutputs];

    inputColumnIndices[0] = 0;
    inputColumnIndices[1] = 1;
    outputColumnIndices[0] = 2;

    initValues(&model);
    initParameters(&model);

    for (int epochIndex = 0; epochIndex < EPOCH_COUNT; epochIndex++)
        train(&model, &trainData, inputColumnIndices, outputColumnIndices);
    
    exit(0);
}
```

**functions.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "functions.h"
#include "math.h"

double applySigmoid(double weightedSum) {
    double eToWSum = pow(M_E, weightedSum);
    return eToWSum / (eToWSum + 1);
}

double applySigmoidDerivative(double activationValue) {
    return activationValue * (1 - activationValue);
}

double applyReLU(double weightedSum) {
    return weightedSum < 0 ? 0 : weightedSum;
}

double applyReLUDerivative(double activationValue) {
    return activationValue == 0 ? 0 : 1;
}

double applyTanH(double weightedSum) {
    return 2 * applyReLU(2 * weightedSum) - 1;
}

double applyTanHDerivative(double activationValue) {
    return 1 - pow(activationValue, 2);
}

double getInitialXavierWeight(double previousLayerSize, double layerSize) {
    return sqrt(2 / previousLayerSize);
}

double getInitialRandomWeight(double previousLayerSize, double layerSize) {
    return ((double) rand() / RAND_MAX) * 0.01;
}

double getInitialBias(double previousLayerSize, double layerSize) {
    return 0;
}

double getCost(double neuronValue, double intendedValue) {
    double difference = neuronValue - intendedValue;

    return 0.5 * pow(difference, 2);
}

double getCostDerivative(double neuronValue, double intendedValue) {
    return neuronValue - intendedValue;
}
```

If any other files are required, please request.

Comment: although they are not partial to buggy code over at _[Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)_ either, that may still be a better place to post this question.  You implied I think that the code builds and runs, but that it is buggy?

Comment: @ryyker When I posted it over there, the moderator put it on hold. It took some convincing to take it off hold, however it has been 5 days and no responses. That's a sign to me that while there is some room for it to be considered topical, from a rules perspective, the community over there does not consider it topical. As for your second question, it compiles and runs fine with exit code 0. I say buggy because the intention of the program is to reduce the cost of the outputs of the neural network, however that fails to happen due to some mathematical error within the program itself.

Comment: For reference, the code review question is: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/197168/neural-network-backpropagation

Comment: While the code you have provided is indication that all the files exist somewhere, they do not exist where anyone that wanted to help could. (Because that usually includes dropping the code example into a compiler to compile, build and run while in a debugger.)

Comment: @ryyker in that case, should I post the GitHub link for the people that wish to actually compile it, while leaving the main files in the question for the people who can spot the error without compilation and debugging?

Comment: That would work for a lot of us.  Do it with apologies so some of the more pedantic among us won't have much to say.